# Ошибка undefined reference to `WinMain@16', но функция main есть

Tags: c++, sfml

Функция main есть, файл сохранён, но линкер выдаёт undefined reference to `WinMain@16'.
Вот код:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "Another Snake");

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Может я плохо ищу, но я нигде не могу найти ответ на этот вопрос, а stackoverflow говорит что это дубликат.

Переименовал main:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <windows.h>

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hInstPrev, PSTR cmdline, int cmdshow) {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "Another Snake");

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Всё равно ошибка.

Comment: `undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'` - значит вы компилируете как оконное приложение, а не консольное. Если компилируете как оконное приложение, то главная функция должна быть WinMain, а не main. В ошибке прямо написано, какое имя у главной функции должно быть.

Comment: заменил main на WinMain, но линкер всё равно выдаёт ошибку undefined reference to `WinMain@16'

Comment: Просто переименовать недостаточно. У нее должно быть 4 параметра: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-winmain

Comment: Переименовал, дал все параметры, но всё равно: undefined reference to `WinMain@16'

Comment: Покажите прямо в вопросе, как у вас код теперь выглядит.

Comment: @insolor Для MinGW (который использует ТС, судя по ошибке), не важно, какую функцию писать - `main` или `WinMain`. Он понимает любую, независимо от того, графическое приложение компилируется или консольное. (В ошибке всегда пишется `WinMain`.)

Comment: @cyxigo Вы точно уверены, что компилируете этот файл? Часто забывают нажать "сохранить" в VSC и ловят эту ошибку, компилируя пустой файл. Как именно вы его компилируете? Какой IDE и/или какой командой?

Comment: так WinMain наверное должна быть extern "C"?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat да я уверен что компилирую именно этот файл причём я его сохранил